# I get division by zero and/or memory access violation when calling sp_track_release()

Tags: c#, .net, libspotify

I have spent some time trying to close my C# app close down in a controlled way.
I have read MSDN section about IDispose carefully and implemented it accordingly.

I have had two types of problems regarding this (and other) release calls:

> SpotifyApi.sp_track_release(trackHandle)

1) division by zero exception occasionally.

2) memory read write access violation occasionally.

In case 2 the problem goes away if I add a call to sp_track_add_ref() before release (as a test). Somehow the reference counter in the lib seems to be zero already!

> sp_track_error() returns SP_ERROR_OK.

Is there a way to test for ref counter zero before release attempt?

Some other workaround you know of?

Comment: Any particular reason you aren't using [libspotify.NET](https://libspotifydotnet.codeplex.com/)? It should handle all these nasty COM and interop calls for you.

Comment: Thanks! I see now that there is a new libspotify.NET since I started my development! Previous version was two years old. I will certainly have another look at it. 
But it seems to me that my problems are more related to "features" in the spotify dll rather than my code.

Comment: The source I found is just the dll imports. Made that myself already, but marshalled in a more platform independent way. Do you mean that I should use jamcast?

Comment: You can use Jamcast if you need to. It depends on your requirements.